# What's "context ?: return binding.root" meaning in Android Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context, android-viewbinding

I am checking Sunflower sample app from Google. And I found an interesting part.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        context ?: return binding.root
        return binding.root
    }
```

Here, it uses `context ?: return binding.root` I don't get it because whether context is null or not, it will return binding.root anyway.

Is there any differences?

Comment: Indeed, a pointless check.

Comment: Google’s examples and Code Labs are full of little errors and weird things like this that don’t make any sense. Context cannot ever be null inside `onCreateView()` either so it is doubly pointless.